# Vaadin web application on tomcat creates only one instance of webapp for all users

Tags: java, vaadin

I've some problems with my English, so I apologize for mistakes.

I'm a beginner in Java programming. I use IntelliJIdea as IDE, Vaadin framework to create GUI and tomcat as a web server. Project was generated with maven.
To create an application I use the following sources as example:

[From stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550399/vaadin-web-xml-setup)

[Video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qFlPAIAljDI)

There is Application class, (it's not `com.vaadin.Application` inheritor), but singleton.

```
package com.exadel.dinnerorders.vaadinwindow.application;
import com.exadel.dinnerorders.entity.Order;
import com.exadel.dinnerorders.entity.User;
import com.exadel.dinnerorders.service.TasksManagerService;
import com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus;

public class Application {
    private EventBus eventBus = new EventBus();
    private static Application INSTANCE = new Application();
    private User user;
    private Order order;
    private TasksManagerService tasksManagerService = new TasksManagerService();

    private Application() {
        tasksManagerService.start();
    }

    public synchronized static Application getInstance(){
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public EventBus getEventBus() {
        return eventBus;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public Order getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(Order order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    public TasksManagerService getTasksManagerService() {
        return tasksManagerService;
    }
}
```

And there is `WebApplicationController` class, which extends `com.vaadin.Application`.

```
package com.exadel.dinnerorders.vaadinwindow.application;

import com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus;
import com.google.common.eventbus.Subscribe;
import com.vaadin.terminal.Sizeable;
import com.vaadin.ui.*;

import java.util.Collection;

public class WebApplicationController extends com.vaadin.Application {
    private EventBus eventBus = Application.getInstance().getEventBus();
    private Layout loginLayout;
    private String datePattern = "YYYY-MM-DD";

    @Override
    public void init() {
        createLayouts();
        createMainWindow();
        eventBus.register(this);
        setTheme("apptheme");
    }
    //some another methods for initialization main window and layouts
}
```

So, it seems my application works fine. But I faced the next problem:
I run application in idea on Tomcat 7 configuration. It launches without any problems. I open Opera as browser and log in as, for example, user1. Everything seems to work correct. Then I open Google Chrome or another browser and log in as user2. And if refresh window in Opera, it will show that know user2 logged in, but not user1. I had tried to do the same in different computers, and I got the same result. (on one machine log as user1, on another as user2).
Firebug shows that sessionsID are different in different browsers.

It seems that the problem are in web.xml file, where I configure servlets. But I had tried different configuration examples, and always got the same result.

Unfortunately, I didn't manage to find answer in google or another forums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that your problem is related to the static Application singleton. Statics are shared among all the users inside a JVM.

Answer (score 2):

As Henri points out, you are using a static Application singleton here. That means every call to `Application#getInstance()` (and, by extension, `WebApplicationController#getInstance`) will return the same Application instance, irrespective of which HTTP session the call is being made from.

If you need easy access to the Application instance from other parts of your web application, the most common approach is to use a `ThreadLocal<Application>` variable to store the instance. By using a `HttpServletRequestListener` you can set the value when the request starts, and clear it when it ends.

For example code, see the second code sample in the [ThreadLocal Pattern](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/ThreadLocal%20Pattern) article on the Vaadin website.

There are other approaches - using Spring or Guice to create and manage the Application instance, but they only make sense if you are already using those frameworks.

It's also worth noting that you can access the Application instance that a Window belongs to by calling `Window#getApplication`; this association is only made when the Window is added to the application, though, and so is not available in the constructor.

Comment: Thank you. I had replaced singleton Application and the web application started to work in correct way.